# Automate bitbucket SQL scripts

Tags: sql, git, bitbucket, devops, octopus

Currently We are using Bitbucket repository for SQL scripts version control and manually deploying the changes to database.

For now we are going to automate the deployment. So Can any one suggest how we can automate the sql scripts from bitbucket repository.

Comment: For what database? BitBucket has a companion product Bamboo for CI/CD. There are options for deploying SQL changes. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?product=bamboo&query=sql

Comment: For MSSQL AWS Database.